# While reading through the password file, the program never encounters EOF

Tags: c, linux, unix

Part of the program that I'm currently writing needs to check whether or not a user exists (this is for a unix system). However, while reading through the password file for users, EOF is never reached, therefore creating an endless loop. What could I be doing wrong?

```
        int readPass;

        int userExists = 0; // 0 means user doesn't exist, 1 means they do

        // open password file to read in usernames
        int passFD = open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY);

        // open password file to read character by character
        FILE* pass = fopen("/etc/passwd", "r");

        // c-string to store usernames
        char passUser[100];

        // read through the password file
        while (readPass != EOF)
        {
            int numPass = 0;

            // read until reaching a colon, this is the username of the current line
            while (readPass != ':')
            {
                readPass = fgetc(pass);
                numPass += 1;
            }
            // store username is a c-string
            read(passFD, passUser, numPass);
            passUser[numPass - 1] = '\0';

            // if the user exists, stop checking
            if ((strcmp(passUser, argv[user])) == 0)
            {
                userExists = 1;
                break;
            }

            // read junk until next line
            readPass = NULL;
            int junksRead = 0;
            char passJunk[100];
            while (junksRead < 6)
            {
                numPass = 0;
                readPass = NULL;
                while (readPass != ':' && readPass != '\n' && readPass != EOF)
                {
                    readPass = fgetc(pass);
                    numPass += 1;
                    //printf("%c\n", readPass);
                }
                read(passFD, passJunk, numPass);
                junksRead += 1;
            }
        }

        // if the user doesn't exist, end the program
        if (userExists == 0)
        {
            printf("%s does not exist\n", argv[user]);
            return 0;
        }`
```

Comment: Why are you assigning `NULL` to an `int`? And you have some internal file reading loops which are not even checking for `EOF`. The code is a complete mess.

Comment: what is this supposed to do: `read(passFD, passUser, numPass);` ? BTW: fgets() is your friend.

Comment: NULL is there because I used to have it as a char and forgot to change it. Also, not all loops would need to check for EOF, only the one that will be reading until the end of the line. For example, reading in the user name will never reach EOF so it's pointless to check.

Comment: That stores the username of the current line in the file to the passUser array

Comment: "reading in the user name will never reach EOF so it's pointless to check" ha, ha, ha, ha, ha, ha

Comment: is that wrong? I figured since the username is the first thing in the file followed by a colon and other information that it couldn't reach eof in that loop.

Comment: Why are you opening the same file with both `open` and `fopen`? On the first iteration of the `while` loop, you test `readPass != EOF` when `readPass` hasn't been initialized. The usual idiom to read by characters is `while ((readPass = fgetc(pass)) != EOF) { /* ... */ }`

Comment: `read(passFD, passUser, numPass);
            passUser[numPass - 1] = '\0';` --> weak code.  Code should check the return value of `read()` before using `passUser`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably getting stuck in one of the other while loops. Make sure each while loop is checking for EOF, particularly:

```
while (readPass != ':' && readPass != EOF)
            {
                readPass = fgetc(pass);
                numPass += 1;
            }
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I just figured since the user name is the first thing in the file that I wouldn't have to check for EOF there. I also thought that the outer loop would catch it if EOF was found in a previous iteration of the loop. Guess I was wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Searching for a user by reading the `/etc/passwd` file all by yourself is fine, if you have no other option. However, the better approach is to use an existing function that can do that for you: [getpwnam()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getpwnam.html) from the header [pwd.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/pwd.h.html). No need to reinvent stuff that already has been done and works.

Possible code could look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
  //reset errno to be able to detect errors
  errno = 0;
  struct passwd * result = getpwnam("username");
  //Return value NULL could either mean error or "user not found".
  if (result == NULL)
  {
    //If errno is not zero, then an error occurred while getpwnam() was called.
    if (errno != 0)
      printf("An error occurred while searching for the user.\n");
    //Otherwise the user just does not exist.
    else
      printf("User does not exist!\n");
  }
  //Not NULL: user was found.
  else
  {
    printf("User exists.\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'll keep that in my for the future, however this is for an assignment for class and I was supposed to write as much of it as possible (within reason) by myself.

Comment: In a real program, you should use `getpwnam` not only because it does the parsing for you, but because it will pick up accounts from NIS, LDAP, etc. if the system has been configured that way.